# How do i add to the listBox another item?

Tags: c#

I have this code in a method im calling the method in a timer every second:

```
data = new List<string>();
data.Add("Gpu Temeprature --- " + sensor.Value.ToString());
listBox1.DataSource = null;
listBox1.DataSource = data;
listBox1.Invalidate();
```

Its updating a value in the listBox every second in the first place as an item.
Now i want to add in the second line a new item so they both will be updated every second so in the timer event im calling another method wich have this code inside:

```
// data = new List<string>();
data.Add("Cpu Temeprature --- " + sensor.Value.ToString());
listBox1.DataSource = null;
listBox1.DataSource = data;
listBox1.Invalidate();
```

If i will use the data = new List(); in the second method it will put both items in the same place in the listBox.
If im not using this data = new List(); then the second one will blink all the time each second will blink and it's not working looking good.

This is the timer event:

```
private void timer2_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (tempCpuValue >= (float?)nud1.Value || tempGpuValue >= (float?)nud1.Value)
    {
        soundPlay = true;
        blinking_label();
        NudgeMe();
    }
    else
    {
        soundPlay = false;
        stop_alarm = true;

    }
    cpuView();
    gpuView();
}
```

cpuView() and gpuView() are the two method im calling in the timer wich updating the listBox.

And i have another two listBox events:

```
private void listBox1_MeasureItem(object sender, MeasureItemEventArgs e)
{
    e.ItemHeight = 25;
}    


private void listBox1_DrawItem(object sender, DrawItemEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Index == -1)
    {
    }
    else
    {
        ColorText.ColorListBox(data, e);
    }
}
```

ColorText is in a new class where im cloring the items in the listBox.

Comment: The problem is how do i add a second item/update the listBox with another sensor.Value value. The first one is ypdating the cpu temperature and now i want to update in the second place/second item the gpu temeperature.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to continue doing it this way you can do the following:

Try moving the data initialization, the datasource, and the invalidation outside of those function blocks as follows:

```
private void timer2_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (tempCpuValue >= (float?)nud1.Value || tempGpuValue >= (float?)nud1.Value)
            {
                soundPlay = true;
                blinking_label();
                NudgeMe();
            }
            else
            {
                soundPlay = false;
                stop_alarm = true;

            }
            data = new List<string>();
            cpuView();
            gpuView();
            listBox1.DataSource = data;
            listBox1.Invalidate();
        }
```

And remove them from the functions so you don't keep doing it twice.

---

This can probably be done more efficiently using BindingList. Change Data to:
BindingList Data = new BindingList();

Then you never need to create a new list. Add the two values you want into this bindinglist and then set the listbox.DataSource = the bindinglist. Then in your GPU/CPU functions you just need to update the index of the list IE:

data[0] = "Cpu Temeprature --- " + sensor.Value.ToString());

and the bindinglist should handle updating the listbox.

Comment: Snukus it's working but now the items in the listBox are blinking every second.

Comment: What do you mean by blinking every second? The items in the box should be changing every time the timer ticks to whatever the sensors tell it to change to. Is it blinking in some other way?

Comment: Its blinking each time it's updating in the timer. Maybe since it's drawing again the items or something with the update.